# Adding the most recent data to a pandas data frame

Tags: pandas, dataframe, time-series

I am trying to build, and keep up to date, a data frame/time series where I scrape the data from a website table, and want to take the most recent data, and add to the data I've already got. A sample of what the data frame looks like is:

```
   Date      Price
0  10/01/19  100
1  09/01/19  95
2  08/01/19  96
3  07/01/19  97
```

What I then want to do is run my little program and have it identify that I am missing data for the 11th and 12th of Jan, and then add it to the top of the data frame. I am quite comfortable with compiling a data frame using .read_html, and generally building a data frame, but this is a bit beyond my talents currently.

I know the done thing is usually to show you what I have so far attempted but to be honest I actually don't know where to begin with this one.

Many thanks

Comment: Do you already have the missing data? are you looking for a way to append and sort the data? please be more specific. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, so each day I would download the data from the website say, but each day will obviously include an extra line of data, so I just want to append the data frame that I'm trying to maintain with the new row of data. However, if I don't reload it for a few days say I want my script to scan the data frame, and the up to data data, and say ok well I only need to append these few lines as it were

Comment: please check if below answer is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say the old dataframe as `df` which looks like:

```
    Date        Price
0   2019-01-10  100
1   2019-01-09  95
2   2019-01-08  96
3   2019-01-07  97
```

After 2 days you download a data which gives you 2 rows for `2019-01-11` and `2019-01-12`, lets name it `new_df` (values are just as examples):

```
    Date        Price
0   2019-01-12  67
1   2019-01-11  89
2   2019-01-10  100
3   2019-01-09  95
```

**Note**: there are a few values in the new df which are present in the old df.

Using [`df.append()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) , [`df.drop_duplicates()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) and [`df.sort_values()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) :-

```
>>df.append(new_df,ignore_index=True).drop_duplicates().sort_values(by='Date',ascending=False)

    Date        Price
4   2019-01-12  67
5   2019-01-11  89
0   2019-01-10  100
1   2019-01-09  95
2   2019-01-08  96
3   2019-01-07  97
```

This will append the new values and sort them in descending manner based on `Date` column keeping the latest date at the top.

if you want the index sorted just add `sort_index()` in the end : `df.append(new_df,ignore_index=True).drop_duplicates().sort_values(by='Date',ascending=False).sort_index()`

Comment: That's great thanks, that is definetly the first part of my problem answered. But if new_df included the old df data PLUS the new days data, how would I append then? Thanks for your help mate

Comment: @topbantz : if the new df already has the old data, why append, just keep the new one and sort values by the Date column as `ascending=False`  as shown in the answer. :)

Comment: I'm terrible at explaining, you make a very good point, and that would be ideal but the website I get my data from only ever displays the last 10 days, so I have to keep a df up to date. Hope that makes sense. If it doesn't don't worry, like I say I'm terrible at explaining things

Comment: @topbantz : the idea is append , then drop any duplicates and then sort decending, check edited answer. :)

Comment: @topbantz : Pleasure, glad I could be of help..!! Cheers. :)